# C# Windows service, cannot get WCF bindings

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services

I want to obtain some data from a WCF service, but when I try to obtain the bindings I get an error;
"No elements matching the key 'GetWorksOrdersListBinding' were found in the configuration element collection"
The exception was thrown on the second line below, the first line was OK;

```
        var endpointAddress = this.GetEndpointAddress("GetWorksOrdersList");
        var binding = this.GetBinding("GetWorksOrdersListBinding");
```

The methods called are;

```
public EndpointAddress GetEndpointAddress(string method)
{
    return new EndpointAddress(this.ServiceUrlRoot + method);
}

public BasicHttpsBinding GetBinding(string binding)
{
    return new BasicHttpsBinding(binding);
}
```

The App.Config file contains the following;

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="GetWorksOrdersDetailBinding" />
        <binding name="GetWorksOrdersListBinding" />
        <binding name="UpdWorksOrdersCompBinding" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://xxxx-test.xxxxxxxxxxxx.co.uk/communication/GetWorksOrdersDetail"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="GetWorksOrdersDetailBinding"
          contract="GetWorksOrdersDetailPort" name="GetWorksOrdersDetailPort" />

      <endpoint address="http://xxxx-test.xxxxxxxxxxx.co.uk/communication/GetWorksOrdersList"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="GetWorksOrdersListBinding"
          contract="GetWorksOrdersListPort" name="GetWorksOrdersListPort" />

      <endpoint address="http://xxxx-test.xxxxxxxxxxx.co.uk/communication/UpdWorksOrdersComp"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="UpdWorksOrdersCompBinding"
          contract="UpdWorksOrdersCompPort" name="UpdWorksOrdersCompPort" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Are you sure `GetWorksOrdersListBinding` is present in WCF service as well(I mean name mismatch might be there)? Your App.Config looks fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The config has a `BasicHttpBinding`, your code is asking for a `BasicHttpsBinding`.

Comment: Thnak you. You are a star!